# What makes an universal mapping unique?

Tags: category-theory, universal-property

Maybe the title doesn't explain very well my question. I was wondering why if some object satisfies an universal property, then for any other object there is one and only one mapping between them. Let me explain myself a little more with an example. Suppose that we have three objects (I think we can suppose they are sets) $A,B$ and $C$ and two maps: $i:A\rightarrow B$ and $j:A\rightarrow C$. Let $h:B\rightarrow C$ be map such that makes commutative the diagram, i.e. $i\circ h = j $ (I use the opposite notation for composition). Under what assumptions for $A,B$ and $C$ and $i$ and $j$ such an $h$ is unique, that is, if $h'$ is another map satisfying $i\circ h' = j$ then $h=h'$.

As you can imagine, the background for this question is universal properties that arises in category theory: products, coproducts, pullbacks, pushouts, etc. can be defined by mean of them, and usually we find statements like for example the product: *The product of two objects $A$ and $B$ is (whenever it exists) an object $C$ together with two maps $p:C\rightarrow A$ and $q:C\rightarrow B$ such that for any other object $D$ and arrows $f:D\rightarrow A$ and $g:D\rightarrow B$ theres is only one morphisms $h:D\rightarrow C$ such that $h\circ p = f$ and $h\circ q=g$*.

I guess that the answer may be related with the span of $A$ and $B$ by $p$ and $q$ (or by the spant of $C$ by $i$ and $j$ if we have a corpoduct). Of course, when I say 'span' I'm not thinking in the usual meaning of the word span in linear algebra. I'm meaning... I don't know what exactly. Maube for **Set** a 'span' could be a surjective function, because then every object of $C$ would be written in terms of the elements of $A$ and $B$ (I'm thinking in coproducts here). Of course for categories like **Ab** span could mean span actually: in the case of direct sums, $i(a)$ and $j(b)$ generates the group $A\oplus B$.

I hope the answer would be clear and interesting and you understand me.

Thanks in advance

EDIT

**To sum up**: I'm not asking why $h$ must be unqiue, but why it is. Which is the reason(s) behind $A,B,C,p$ and $q$ (or $i$ and $j$) for make $h$ unique.

For the product (coproduct) of two objects, it can be define as a final object in the comma category. Then, by definition of final (initial) object, $h$ is unique. I suppose it can be extend to an arbitrary family of objects, but I haven't got enough knowledge. But that would be another answer. Then, my questions would be, what about pullbacks and pushouts and direct and inverse limits?

EDIT 2: (Explanation for 'span')

I'm studying at this moment the pushout of two maps in **Set** and I think it is a good example to explain what I mean by ''span''. as you know perfectly, the pushout of two maps $f:X\rightarrow A$ and $g:X\rightarrow B$ is the set $A\coprod B$ quotient by the finest equivalence relation $(f(x),0)\sim (g(x),1)$ and the maps $i_A=\iota_A\circ \pi$ and $i_B=\iota_B \circ \pi$, where $\pi$ is the canonical projection onto $A\coprod B/\sim$ and $\iota_A$ and $\iota_B$ are the inclusions of $A$ and $B$ into the disjoint union. Let me call $Y=A\coprod B/\sim$.

For any other set $Z$ and maps $j_A:A\rightarrow Z$ and $j_B:B\rightarrow Z$ satisfying $f\circ j_A=g\circ j_B$ I define a map $h:Y\rightarrow Z$. You know better than me how this map must be defined. So come on to the interesting part: this pam $h$ satisfies $i_A\circ h = j_A$ and $i_B\circ h = j_B$. And now, if $h':Y\rightarrow Z$ is any other map satisfying the same conditions, then $h=h'$, and that is because for any $y\in Y$, $y$ must be of the form $i_A(a)$ or $i_B(b)$ (maybe both at the same time) so the commuting condition defines $h'$ for all $y\in Y$.

A similar case happens in the corpoduct of two abelian groups for example. Every element of $A\oplus B$ can be express as the product of $\iota_A(a)$ and $\iota_B(b)$, so again the commuting relations determine the map completely.

Comment: Do you mean $j\colon A\to C$?

Comment: Yes. It is a typo. Thanks. I correct it.

Comment: Are you asking specifically why $h$ has to be unique in the given definition of the product, or something else?

Comment: @BenWest: No, I'm not asking why it must be unique but why it is. I mean, it is, but why? Which is the reason behind its uniqueness?

Comment: Guys, I have added an edit summarizing my question and adding a well-known (and useful?) comment about products and coproducts. Thanks.

Comment: Just a note on notation: $\circ$ is rather used for right to left composition, for left to right composition it's more usual to use semicolon ($i;h$) or simple juxtaposition ($ih$)..

Comment: @Berci: Very useful comment: I'll take it into account for my futures notes.

Comment: @BenWest: Yes, yes. It is desirable, of course. But my question is: Why these objects and morphisms have these property and others don't? Why they are special? Which is ''the condition'' that ensures that, if I take objects and morphisms sitifying it, they will be universal?

Answer (score 3):

A way to define what is a universal mapping problem is through *representability*.

A functor $F : \mathcal C^{\rm op}\to \mathbf{Set}$ is said to be representable if there exists $X\in\mathcal C$ and a natural **isomorphism**
$$ \alpha : F \to  \mathcal C(-,X) $$
Denote $x$ the unique element of $F(X)$ such that $\alpha_X(x) = \mathrm{id}_X$. Now the naturality of $\alpha$ gives the following property:

> For any element $y\in F(Y)$, there is a **unique** $h: Y \to X$ such that $F(h)(x) = y$.

*Proof.* By naturality of $\alpha$, and for any map $k: Z \to X$, we have $k = \alpha_Z(F(k)(x))$. Denote $h = \alpha_Y(y)$, then it gives
$$ \alpha_Y(y)  = \alpha_Y(F(h)(x)) $$
But $\alpha_Y$ is injective, so $y = F(h)(x)$ and $h$ answer to the problem. Now if there is another $h':Y \to X$ such that $F(h')(x)= y$, then $h' = \alpha_Y(F(h')(x)) = \alpha_Y(y) = h$. This proves the uniqueness of $h$.

So the answer to "why is $h$ unique" is that universal mapping problem requires an $\alpha$ which is both natural and bijective in each component. Remove either of this condition to $\alpha$ and you would have a "generalized notion of universal mapping problem" where the uniqueness of $h$ is no longer required. (Also, this generalized version would be clearly less interesting, but that is another issue.)

---

Here is the link of the above presentation with the examples you gave in you post.

Given a category $\mathcal A$, if you take $\mathcal C = \mathcal A$ and $F = \mathcal C(-,A) \times \mathcal C(-,B)$ for some fixed $A,B$, then an $X$ representing $F$ is actually a product for $A,B$ and the $x\in F(X)$ is given by the projections $(\pi_A,\pi_B)$.

Given a category $\mathcal A$, if you take $\mathcal C = \mathcal A^{\rm op}$ and $F = \mathcal A(A,-) \times \mathcal (B,-)$ for some fixed $A,B)$, then an $X$ representing $F$ is a coproduct for $A,B$ and the $x\in F(X)$ is given by the inclusions $(i_A,i_B)$.

Comment: Very interesting answer. I had ignored representations because I thought they were useless for my purpose. I was very very wrong. Is valid the formalism of your answer for other structures, as pullbacks and inverse limits? By the way, I have added a second edit trying to explain what I wanted to mean by 'span'.